# Keeping both files with auto rename when copying

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files

When copying 10 files from a folder to another, which already has those 10 files, 3 options are given,

a) keep latest
b) replace with the one you are dragging
c) renaming to keep both

Is it possible to have auto rename in option c of all files to keep both copies, just like in Windows 10? Manual renaming to avoid conflict is alright for 1 or 2 files, but if you are copying 10-15 files then auto renaming will be more productive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise an issue at https://github.com/elementary/files/issues (after checking for duplicates).  You should specify what form you want the auto-renaming to take, e.g. adding "-(copy)" to the filename, rather than referencing another OS.